# Problems with configChanges and AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I too have problems with configChanges and AdMob.  Though I've read lots of posts regarding the issue and know how to "fix" it.

The fix is to set target=android-13 or above.  Now how can this be a fix when I now cannot even run the program as my device is not 3.2 or above?

Does this mean that AdMob cannot be utilized on systems lower than Android 3.2?

If I set target=android-7 I get an error on configChanges.  If I set target=android-13 or above I get an error trying to run this on my device that is only 2.3.6, saying it requires 3.2.

How to fix this fix?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  It gives an error when I press Run, but pressing Ok in the Run menu will install and run the application on my device.  This is in Eclipse, btw.